# Tailwind CSS - change parent div when radio-button checked

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a table with multiple columns and a radio button in each row. When I select a certain button, I need to change the background color in the whole row. Is this even possible to implement?

```
<tr class="flex items-center p-4 space-x-4 border hover:bg-indigo-50">
<input type="radio" name="user" id="{{ user.id }}">
<label for="{{ user.id }}">{{ user.email }}</label>
<div>{{ user.name }}</div>
</tr>
```

In Tailwind it is possible to style neighboring blocks using the "peer" class. But I need to stylize the parent block (when  is checked, the background color should change in the parent -block).

Comment: Is your HTML correct? input, label, div are not allowed as direct children of a tr. Perhaps you could make your code into a runnable snippet?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the pseudo class `:has()` but it has a limited browser support (For example: It doesn't work on Mozilla). You can check the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas()) for this selector.

```css
tr:has(input:checked){
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<table>
    <tr class="flex items-center p-4 space-x-4 border hover:bg-indigo-50">
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="user" id="{{ user.id }}">
            <label for="{{ user.id }}">{{ user.email }}</label>
            <div>{{ user.name }}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```